# How are tube amps constructed?

Tags: amplifier

need a Little HISTORY about Tube Amplifiers or Tube Sound,

need Signal Processing theory of the same, Its Schematics

and

importantly need how it is RE-Modeled into a DSP Plugin. (either by Programming or Capturing Impulse Responses)

Please Help me..

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong forum for this question. You'd get better answers e.g. from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or https://dsp.stackexchange.com/.

The fundamentals of tube amplification are to be found in electrical engineering "theory". And specifically, what a vacuum tube is and how it operates. The software counterpart (DSP) basically only models (by using equations that are known in physics of electromagnetism and by knowing how a tube amplifier operates on the signal that passes through it) what happens in the electrical implementations.

For capturing an impulse response, check google.

Answer (score 0):

Really Good SOS article I just found:

http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/aug10/articles/modelling-plugins.htm

Answer (score 0):

Mesa/Boogie has a document posted with a basic explanation of how tube amps operate.

Class A: Exposed and Explained by Randall Smith

http://www.mesaboogie.com/US/Smith/ClassA.htm

It is geared towards guitarists, but is, in any case, helpful.